# r Reference variable by string then change that variable

Tags: r, string, variables, replace

So, basically, I'm writing a for function that instead of subbing in say 1:5 it actually subs in strings that are the names of variables. But I also want to be able to alter the variable itself which in my case are dataframes.
Basically want I would like is:

```
x = c("item")
item = data.frame(c(1,1,1,1))
```

then by only using x or "item" I want to actually alter a value in item such as changing the second 1 into a 5.

So, far the best I've been able to do in the department of referencing a variable by a string is:

```
eval(parse(text = x))
```

Which only gives me the data in item. I actually want to change the data inside item itself and have it stay changed.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  I think you're reinventing the wheel.  The tidyverse package has essentially already done this for you.  For example, `df <- df %>% mutate(X=ifelse(Row_number() == 2, 5, X)` will change the value of `X` in the second row of `df` to `5`, leaving all other values unchanged.

Comment: Change your approach. It's just bad practice and will be very cumbersome for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get` to get the dataframe from string value `transform` to change the value.

```
item = data.frame(col = c(1,1,1,1))
x = "item"
res <- transform(get(x), col = replace(col, 2, 5))
res

#  col
#1   1
#2   5
#3   1
#4   1
```

If you want to keep the same name as your original dataframe you can use `assign`.

```
assign(x, transform(get(x), col = replace(col, 2, 5)))
```